Conditional Formatting Equation for a Max value within a Date Range in a Column with Variable number of Rows
I want to do a conditional format on values in a column based on a date range of dates in another column.  Both columns have the same number of rows, but the number of rows is a variable.  I can get the max row number of this data by doing a COUNT function on the date column (the dates are in ascending order) but I have not been able to figure out how to apply that max value in a conditional formatting expression range that does not cause an error.  For conditional formatting, this does not work.
=$E1=MAX(IF(YEAR(INDIRECT("$a"&MaxRow))=YEAR($A$2:INDIRECT("$a"&MaxRow)),$E$2:INDIRECT("$e"&MaxRow),""))

where MaxRow is a variable that is equal to count(a:a)+1

So what are you trying to highlight?

The max value within a year for each year for which I have data.

Format column E from E2 downwards using formula:
=AND(E2=MAXIFS(E:E,A:A,">="&DATE(YEAR(A2),1,1),A:A,"<"&DATE(YEAR(A2)+1,1,1)),ISNUMBER(E2))



Thanks for your quick response.  This is exactly what I needed.  Works great!!

Alternate soltution using Office 365 applied to E2 and down:
=(E2=MAX((YEAR(A2)=YEAR(TOCOL(A:A,1)))*TOCOL(E:E,1)))*ISNUMBER(E2)


This takes the non-blanks from column A and converts it to year value and compares it to equal the year value of the current row in column A; If year resembles (TRUE) this results in 1, else 0.
This array is multiplied by the non-blanks from column E resulting in 1 or 0 times the value in column E.
The max of that array is the max number for that year. So if we check if the value from the current row in column E equals that max value, we get our end result being TRUE or FALSE.
The *ISNUMBER(E2) is to exclude false positives for the conditional formatting applied to the rows where column A en E are both empty.
